# Redirecting same page along with Success Message

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have Save and New button in registration form when i hit that button it will create a record and redirect to new registration form along with the success message "Record created". I'm using this code it will redirect only but not showing the success message.

```
insert CasePOs;
PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/BigW_Booking_Request_Sort');
pg.setRedirect(true);
ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Created Successfully.Thank you!'));
return pg;
```

Comment: try by setting setRedirect to false, since setRedirect(true) causes the viewstate to flush.

Comment: thanks for replay anmrk i tried setRedirect(false) its show an success message and reload the same page with inserted value. i want new page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this Code in Constructor

```
        String message = '' + ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('message');
        String pageHeaderReferer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer'); 

        // Use the referrer parameter to only show the message when coming from Page 1
        if(pageHeaderReferer != null && pageHeaderReferer.containsIgnoreCase('PageName') && message != 'null')
        {
               ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, message)); 
        }
```

This code add in save method

```
       PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/PageName');
       pg.getParameters().put('message', 'Your Message here');
       pg.setRedirect(true);
       return pg;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're redirecting to the same page, then just return null for the PageReference.  Also, if you have any rerender logic, verify that the apex:pageMessages tag is rerendered.

What your action may look like in Apex:

```
public PageReference myAction(){
    try{
        insert CasePOs;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Record Created Successfully.Thank you!'));
    }catch(DMLException e){
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Record creation failed: ' + e.getMessage()));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @James Loghry. If I give return null for the page reference as expected success message will be displayed but the issue is previously entered informations are still available in the form. But as per the requirement If I click the Save and New button the page should display with the new page and success message.Hope this is clear now. Can you pls help me out in this?

Comment: Gotcha.  In that case, you could instantiate a new object in your controller.  If casePOs is the object your form uses, for instance, then call casePOs = new List<sobject>(); or whatever the constructor is in the myAction method.

Answer (score 1):

try by setting setRedirect to false, also after inserting the records create a new instance of your CasePO instance before redirecting.